# How to set props equal to dynamic value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an array of Components:

```
myArray = [<Component isDisabled={myfunction}/>,<Component isDisabled ={myfunction}/>]
```

and then mapping it out

```
myArray.map((comp, index) => (comp))
```

I am trying to conditionally set the value of isDisabled prop with a function:

```
myfunction ()
{
return false
}
```

It is not working. I have tried to use arrow functions

```
<Component isDisabled={()=>myfunction()}/>
<Component isDisabled={()=>(myfunction())}/>
<Component isDisabled={()=>{myfunction()}}/>
```

Comment: I think you just want `isDisable={myfunction()}`. FYI if your array already contains JSX elements, you don't need to map it... `{myArray}` is all you need

Comment: I have a question? Will the function only execute once or will it execute every time the component renders?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value of prop "isDisabled" to boolean, you are passing the whole function to it. If you want isDisabled prop to be the result of myFunction execution, you need to write it this way:

```
<Component isDisabled={myFunction()} />
```

Comment: The code worked thank you. I have a question? Will the function only execute once or will it execute every time the component renders?

Comment: It will execute every time the component renders. If you want get rid of unneeded function calls, you can add memoization https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations but it should be used wisely, so read the docs before deciding if you need it or not. Also, please mark the answer as "accepted" it the code worked:)